# Best function getting 0 for odd parameter, 1 for even

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking for two functions, assuming *x* is an integer:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}0&\text{if x is odd}\\1&\text{if x is even}\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}1&\text{if x is odd}\\ 0&\text{if x is even}\end{cases} 
$$

For now I went up with the following :
$$
f(x) = \frac{\cos(x\pi)+1}{2}
$$
and
$$
g(x) = -\frac{\cos(x\pi)-1}{2}
$$

Is there any better / faster way ?

Comment: You mean you wanted continuous functions with this property? Because what you defined in the first line were fine function definitions.

Comment: What about just using the mod function: $g(x)=mod(x,2)$

Comment: This should evaluate pretty fast: ``min(abs x', abs(x'-2)) where x' = x `mod` 2``

Comment: In C or most C-like languages, `g(x)=abs(x)%2` is good enough. For $f(x)$, use `1-g(x)` or even `!g(x)`

Comment: What does fast mean in your question - you are talking about some implementation in a computer language?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since parity isn't defined on $\mathbb{R}$, I assume you want $x$ to be an integer $n$, in which case your functions simplify to
$$f(n) = \frac{1 + (-1)^n}{2}$$
and
$$g(n) = -\frac{(-1)^n - 1}{2} = \frac{1 + (-1)^{n+1}}{2}.$$

Comment: +1 Of course, given any $f(x)$ satisfying this, $g(x)=1-f(x)$ is good for $g$. :)

Comment: In this case, $1-f(n) = 1-\frac{1}{2}(1+(-1)^n)=\frac{1}{2}(2-1-(-1)^n)=\frac{1}{2}(1-(-1)^n)=\frac{1}{2}(1+(-1)^{n+1})$ *is* $g(n)$.

Comment: Yeah, was just noting that it works in general, whatever $f(x)$ is. Although I don't see how this $f(n)$ is particularly "fast." Certainly, faster than computing cosine. But OPs original question is odd, since the definitions at the top are essentially the most efficient ways to implement the functions....

Answer (score 1):

Use the remainder function for division by two or test for the lowest bit.
Fast depends on your language.

\begin{align}
g(x) &= x - 2 \lfloor x / 2 \rfloor \\
f(x) &= 1 - g(x)
\end{align}

In C like languages:

```
odd = x % 2   // use abs(x) for negative x if 
              // your lang uses the dividend's sign
```

or

```
odd = x & 1:
```

the logical negative case:

```
even = (x % 2 == 0)
even = (x & 1 == 0)
```

Comment: Technically, `x%2` returns negative values when `x` is negative, so your first odd is wrong. (I really hate that about C's `%`.) And no, I didn't downvote. Someone randomly downvoted my answer, too.

Comment: I would recommend a test, if one needs to adjust the sign, see this table about the behaviour for negative arguments: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: I tested it already myself, with a program that computed `(-11)%2`, GCC on a MacOS X. But I used to test C compilers for a living, so I was pretty sure of the result.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that problematic. The question is still fuzzy.